# Angular mat table - get click event working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I would like to select an item (row) of my mat table in my Angular app. Therefore I am using the Angular Material. I think I don't know the right place to add the **(click)-event** or do I have to do it in another way? Thanks for helping!

```
<div class="table-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="item_id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="item_name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" (click)="onSelect(item)"> {{item.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

The example is'nt working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Try like this

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click) = "click('aaa')" > {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

[**Working Plunker link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/q9DF2BAYLIjbswQgpfZR?p=preview)

Click on first columns of the table

Comment: Thanks! That was fast! The alert is working in my app, too. But not my other function. But then there must be another problem. I try to solve it in my own. Thanks!

Comment: But how can I change the mouse icon from arrow to the hand. Do you know?

Comment: @dafna change css cursor for the element to this `{ cursor: pointer; }`

Comment: Working! Thanks! :)